# How to log a scalar that is not part of a graph to tensorboard?

Tags: tensorboard

Some scalar calculated in a loop, not part of a graph, calculated in between fit. How can this be pushed to tensorboard?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a node (dummy node) which calculates the quantity you want and then push that value on the tensorboard.

If a sample of your code is given, that might make it easier to figure out how around doing it.